# How to set the axis (x and y) value Microsoft Excel 2013

Tags: excel

How can I set the Y-axis(the red box) value to be 2^n (such as: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, and so on). So the blue will be change to be a string line (in 45 degrees).
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Excel itself:

- Click on your diagram
- Right-click on the y-axis
- `Format Axis`
- Check `Logarithmic scale`
- Change `Base` to 2

In VBA: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822493.aspx

Comment: Thank you so much! But I just wondering that can I set any non-pattern like random number, such as 1, 5, 9, 37, 78, 347 and so on?

Comment: Not that I am aware of any straightforward way of doing so, Excel wasn't meant for such things.

Comment: Got you. Thank you for your help